# Having trouble with sqlite3 ssh command (I am assuming bad quotes)

Tags: ssh, quoting, sql

The following works great:

```
ssh plxch1035.pdx.xxxxxx.com "sqlite3 /p/hdk/rtl/proj_data/shdk74/fe_data/ipci/ipci.db 'select * from tools'"
```

When I want a specific tool row though:

```
ssh plxch1035.pdx.xxxxxx.com "sqlite3 /p/hdk/rtl/proj_data/shdk74/fe_data/ipci/ipci.db 'select * from tools where name='bscan''"
```

The error is

```
SQL error: no such column: bscan
```

I have confirmed the existence of the column name has `bscan`.

I am assuming my quotes are messed up and I even tried escaping the single quotes around `bscan` (using ''')

Answer (score 1):

OT1H `ssh` does not require that the remote command line be a single argument; OTOH getting quotes through both the local shell (to ssh) *and* the remote shell (to sqlite3) is difficult, but sqlite3 accepts SQL command(s) (with ;) on stdin instead of as an argument which is easier because ssh normally passes through stdin (and stdout and stderr) transparently:

```
 echo "select * from tools where name='bscan';" | ssh [user@]host sqlite3 db
```

or if your shell supports herestring (bash, ksh, zsh):

```
 ssh [user@]host sqlite3 db <<<"select * from tools where name='bscan';"
```

Comment: Definitely glad you showed up thank you for the help. Works like a charm!